# How to get client ip address in HttpHandler (Julia Language)?

Tags: http, julia, httpserver

I need to get client's IP address in regular HttpHandler like this:

```
http = HttpHandler() do req::Request, res::Response
    Response( ismatch(r"^/hello/",req.resource) ? string("Hello ", split(req.resource,'/')[3], "!") : 404 )
end
```

Neither `req` nor `http.sock` contain this information.

Comment: The answer is in [the source](https://github.com/JuliaLang/HttpServer.jl/blob/29a053230e7992a5cd3072dd600ba309e0a05afa/src/HttpServer.jl#L274).  In short, you can't right now.  It's not that complicated, but I don't understand why it sends the handler an empty Response() instead of the client — it might be able to be changed.  This is much better suited as an issue on HttpServer.jl instead of StackOverflow.  I recommend [opening one](https://github.com/JuliaLang/HttpServer.jl/issues/new).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to waTeim's answer, but it's from 2014 and things changed in Julia. This works nicely in Julia 6.0 and probably all above:

`function ip(socket::TCPSocket)
    buffer = Array{UInt8}(32)
    bufflen::Int64 = 32
    ccall(:uv_tcp_getpeername,Int64,(Ptr{Void},Ptr{UInt8},Ptr{Int64}), socket.handle, buffer, &bufflen)
    peername::IPv4 = IPv4(buffer[5:8]...)
end`

Answer (score 5):

#### The Approach

This can be done, if you know the internals of Julia a little.  It turns out that Julia uses the library ***[libuv](https://github.com/joyent/libuv)*** for low level system processing and that library has a function called **uv_tcp_getpeername**.  This function is not exported by Julia.Base, but you can gain access to it via [ccall](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/calling-c-and-fortran-code/).  Also, the module ***HttpServer*** allows for way define a callback for various events, including the *connect* event.

#### Example Module

```
module HTTPUtil
   export get_server
   using HttpServer

   function handle_connect(client)
      try
         buffer = Array(Uint8,32)
         bufflen::Int64 = 32

         ccall(:uv_tcp_getpeername,Int64,(Ptr{Void},Ptr{Uint8},Ptr{Int64}),client.sock.handle,buffer,&bufflen)

         peername::IPv4 = IPv4(buffer[5:8]...)
         task_local_storage(:ip,peername)
      catch e
         println("Error ... $e")
      end
   end

   function get_server()
      http = HttpHandler() do req::Request, res::Response
         ip = task_local_storage(:ip)
         println("Connection received from from $ip")
         Response(ismatch(r"^/hello/",req.resource)?string("Hello ",split(req.resource,'/')[3], " $(ip)!") : 404 )
      end

      http.events["connect"]=(client)->handle_connect(client)
      server = Server(http)
   end
end
```

#### Explained

Each time a connection request is made, a peer socket is created by the server, and the *connect* handler is called which is defined to be **handle_connect**.  It takes one parameter, client, of type [***Client***](https://github.com/JuliaLang/HttpServer.jl/blob/master/src/HttpServer.jl#L93).  A ***Client*** type has a field called **sock** of type [***TcpSocket***](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/socket.jl#L242), and a ***TcpSocket*** has a field *handle* which is used by ***libuv***.  The object, then is each time a connection request is made, the connect handler is called, which calls **uv_tcp_getpeername** with the data contained in the ***TcpSocket*** handle.  A byte array is declared to act as a buffer, which then is cast back to [Base.IPv4](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/socket.jl#L4).  The module HTTPServer creates exactly [1 task for each client using @async](https://github.com/JuliaLang/HttpServer.jl/blob/master/src/HttpServer.jl#L215), so the ip address can be stored local to the client using **task_local_storage**; thus there is no race condition.

#### Using it

```
julia> using HTTPUtil
julia> server = get_server()
Server(HttpHandler((anonymous function),TcpServer(init),Dict{ASCIIString,Function} with 3 entries:
  "error" => (anonymous function)
  "listen" => (anonymous function)
  "connect" => (anonymous function)),nothing)

julia> @async run(server,8000)
Listening on 8000...
Task (queued) @0x000000000767e7a0

julia> Connection received from from 192.168.0.23
Connection received from from 192.168.0.22
... etc
```

#### Notes

1. For illustration, the output is modified so that the server will respond to each browser "Hello *ipaddr*"
2. This should be included in Base and/or HttpServer, but currently is not, so you'll need to use this workaround until it is.
3. The typical looping structure is used in **get_server** to illustrate there is no requirement for it to change, except to add in the ip address.
4. Assumes IPv4, but can be improved to allow both IPv4 and IPv6 straightforwardly as ***libuv*** supports both.

Answer (score 1):

Building on the excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24718263/182469) from waTeim I simplified things a little to work with IPv6, and also for SSL connections:

```julia
using MbedTLS

function handle_connect(client)
    ip, port = getsockname(isa(client.sock, MbedTLS.SSLContext) ? client.sock.bio : client.sock)
    task_local_storage(:ip, ip)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

(Would have added this as a comment to Josh Bode's answer, but I don't have the necessary reputation.)

Note that it is necessary to use `getpeername()` instead of `getsockname()` as of Julia v0.7.

https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/21825

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your situation, you may be able to pass a linux command.

```
userIP = strip(readstring(`hostname -i`), ['\n'])
```